# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

Hi added the code for closed the side window

```
if(jQuery(window).width()>=320){
    jQuery(".side-nav-button").on("click tap", function() {
        jQuery(".side-nav-container").toggleClass("showNav hideNav").removeClass("side-nav-hide");
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("animated");
     });
}
```

This is the code i used.
I got the error message " Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function"

Please check where i made mistake

Comment: Which jquery version you have used?

Comment: Try using $ and check if jquery library is loaded properly

Comment: hi manoj. I am using v=1.10.2

Answer (score 1):

> [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
>
> **Description:** Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.
>   version added: 1.7

The `.on()` method have been added in the version 1.7 of jQuery, so check wheter your jQuery have a version >= 1.7 or if you reference jQuery correctly.

An older alternative of `.on()` is `.live()`

> [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
>
> **Description:** Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.
>   version added: 1.3, version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9

Also, try using `$(".side-nav-button")` instead of `jQuery(".side-nav-button")` (Also on the other call of jQuery).

Maybe you have a conflict between jQuery and another library, in this case I advice you to read about [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/):

And you can wrap your jQuery code like this (Giving an `alias` to jQuery):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    // More code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
```

This way jQuery won't conflict with other libraries

Comment: Hi Gille.

sorry for late reply. If change the .on to .live its show me .live is not a function.

Comment: @vigneshr Do you know your version of jquery ?

Comment: I am using v=1.10.2

Comment: @vigneshr Hard to tell, `.on()` should work on this version, can you provide some relevant HTML please ?

Comment: there is some Conflict with this js. This function i am using in drupal 7

Comment: @vigneshr Drupal have its own jQuery librairy (as seen on [Multiple different versions of jQuery co-existing](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/multiple-different-versions-of-jquery-co-existing)). Can you just try without your jQuery loaded ? You can also try to put `jQuery.noConflict();` in the beginning of your js